# 'Controversy' Pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

May I please ask whether there is a definitive as to whether the word should be pronounced 'contr-o-versy', or 'contro-versy', as this has baffled me for years! There appears to be a difference in pronunciation between how the English and the North Americans pronounce it, but it would be good to understand both why this is the case and which of the options is more correct?

Thank you.

Comment: In the U.S., the North American pronunciation is more correct. In the U.K., the British pronunciation is more correct.

Comment: There are many words that are pronounced (and/or spelt) differently between British & N.Americans.

Answer (score 1):

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/controversy):

> There are two possible pronunciations of the word **controversy**: one puts the stress on the **con-** and the other puts it on the **-trov-**. The former pronunciation is the more traditional, but the latter is now more widespread in British English.

As to why this is the case? I can guess. The prefix *con-* is quite common in English, and many words beginning *con-* are accented on the second syllable:

> containment,
>   conception,
>   contingent,
>   contentment,
>   convertible.

The word *controversy* is [etymologically](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=controversy) *contra-* + *verse*, so accenting the *trov* doesn't make sense etymologically. But most English speakers don't know etymologies, and don't take them into account when deciding on pronunciation.